# Microsoft Dynamics AX - Change Label Globally

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I want to globally change a label in the system, meaning all users will see the change. (Unlike personalizing it and only having the effect for your user)

Normally I would go into AOT -> Tools -> Labels -> Label editor

This will allow me to find and change labels for table-like labels or column names. But in this particular case, I want to change a label on a Sales Order header. For example, the "Customer Reference" field.

[image]

Again, if I try to look this field up in the label editor I find nothing. However, if I looked up "Product Name" on the line details table, I would find it.

Any help or if someone can just point me in the right direction for changing labels Globally would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label is on `\Data Dictionary\Extended Data Types\CustRef` and is `@SYS23010`.

Change it there and it will reflect everywhere it is used.